# Summation of a summation

Tags: calculus

Evaluate:

$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{x+y+|x-y|}}$$

So far I have tried separating the $\frac{1}{2^{x+y+|x-y|}}$ into factors which would allow me to sum geometric series, but I cannot get rid of the pesky absolute value. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\geq y$ then $x-y\geq 0\rightarrow \left| x-y\right| +x+y=x-y+x+y=2x$

The series becomes
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{x+y+|x-y|}}=\sum _{y=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{x=y}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2^{2 x}}\right)=\sum _{y=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{x=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4^x}-\sum _{x=0}^{y-1} \frac{1}{4^x}\right)=$$
$$=\sum _{y=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^y}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\right)=\frac{4}{3}\sum _{y=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{ 4^y}=\frac{16}{9}$$
If $x<y$ then $x-y<0$ and we have  $\left| x-y\right| +x+y=-x+y+x+y=2y$ and the series becomes
$$\sum _{y=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{x=0}^{y-1} \frac{1}{2^{2 y}}\right)=\sum _{y=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{x=0}^{y-1} \frac{1}{4^y}\right)=\frac{4}{9}$$
Therefore the series has the sum $\dfrac{16}{9}+\dfrac{4}{9}=\dfrac{20}{9}$

Answer (score 0):

This is
$$\sum_{x,y=0}^\infty\frac1{4^{\max(x,y)}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{4^n}$$
where $a_n$ is the number of pairs $(x,y)$ with $\max(x,y)=n$.
Can you find $a_n$ and compute the resulting series?

Answer (score 0):

This is
$$\eqalign{\sum_{x,y\ge0}\frac{1}{4^{\max(x,y)}}&=2\sum_{x=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{y=x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^y}\right)-\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^{x}}\cr
&=2\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{4^{-x}}{1-1/4}-\frac{1}{1-1/4}\cr
&=\frac83\cdot\frac{4}{3}-\frac{4}{3}=\frac{20}{9}
}$$